# Positive semi definiteness of complex matrices [CSIR 2015]

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following subsets of the complex plane:

$$
\Omega_1=\left\{ C\in \mathbb{C} :  \begin{bmatrix}
        1  & C\\
        \overline C &1
        \end{bmatrix}\text{ is positive semi-definite} \right\}
$$

$$
\Omega_2=\left\{ C\in \mathbb{C} :  \begin{bmatrix}
        1  & C &C\\
        \overline C &1 &C\\
        \overline C & \overline C & 1
        \end{bmatrix}\text{ is positive semi-definite} \right\}
$$

Let $\overline {\mathbb{D}}= \{z \in \mathbb{C} :\vert z \vert \le 1\}$.Then

1. $\Omega_1=\overline {\mathbb{D}},\Omega_2=\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.
2. $\Omega_1\neq\overline {\mathbb{D}},\Omega_2=\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.
3. $\Omega_1=\overline {\mathbb{D}},\Omega_2\neq\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.
4. $\Omega_1\neq\overline {\mathbb{D}},\Omega_2\neq\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.

$\Omega_1$ is positive semidefinite implies that its determinant $1-\vert z \vert^2 \ge 0$ impliying that $\vert z \vert \le 1$.Thus $\Omega_1=\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.

As far as $\Omega_2$  is concerned it being positive semi definite would suggest that the determinant of every principal submatrix of $\Omega_2$ is non-negative.
The two diagonal ones which are basically same as $\Omega_1$ give 
$z \in \mathbb{C} :\vert z \vert \le 1$.But the other submatrices result in the relation that $z^2-z$  is real and non-negative.This definitely means:

$\Omega_2\neq \overline {\mathbb{D}}$. Right?

That would mean 3 is the right answer? Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand: is $\Omega_1$ a set of complex numbers? What does "$\Omega_1$ is positive semi-defined" mean, then?

Comment: Also: did you mean, for instance, this? $$\Omega_1=\left\{c\in\mathbb C:\begin{bmatrix}1&c\\\overline c&1\end{bmatrix}\text{ is positive semi-defined}\right\}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli this looks promising

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes,that is what i meant to say but couldn't write it that way..

Comment: Ok, but what does the "$\Omega_1$ is semi-definite", in the second part, mean? Did you mean "$z\in\Omega_1$ if and only if the matrix (etc...) is semi-definite, which implies that its determinant $1-|z|^2$ is $\ge 0$ " ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ,yes

Answer (score 3):

1. Indeed, $\Omega_1=\overline{\mathbb D}$ because the application of Sylvetser's criterion to this case yields that $A(z)=\begin{bmatrix}1&z\\\overline z&1\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $\det A(z)=1-|z|^2\ge 0$.
2. It holds $\Omega_2\neq\overline{\mathbb D}$, and, though one could use Sylvester's criterion in a more subtle way, I think the easiest way to show it is the following.

   > Let $z\in\mathbb C$. $\det \begin{bmatrix}1&z&z\\ \overline z &1&z\\ \overline z &\overline z &1\end{bmatrix}=1-3|z|^2+2|z|^2\mathfrak{Re}\,z \implies-1\in \overline{\mathbb{D}}\setminus\Omega_2$